# Heuristic value in A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am learning A* algorithm and dijkstra algorithm. And found out the only difference is the Heuristic value it used by A* algorithm. But how can I get these Heuristic value in my graph?. I found a example graph for A* Algorithm(From A to J). Can you guys help me how these Heuristic value are calculated.[image]

The RED numbers denotes Heuristic value.

My current problem is in creating maze escape.

Comment: The `A*` algorithm can be used to solve many problems. The heuristic depends on the problem. You didn't specify what problem do you want to solve.

Comment: Yes, sry I forgot to mention my problem, 
I am creating 2D maze escape game and thinking to use A* as based algorithm. In that problem, how should i calculate heuristic value? @axiac

Comment: A* heuristics are functions that must be **admissable** and **monotone**. Every function that fulfills this is possible. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/fkRMIrS.jpg) is a slide on this with some intuition. A common simple heuristic is *as-the-crows-fly*. However, it is pretty bad for road networks and even worse for transit networks. The choice really depends on your application. There is also a generic heuristic solution called **landmarks** that performs well on many graphs. However, it needs much pre-computation and space.

Comment: There you choose some nodes and for all of them you pre-compute all shortest path distances to all other nodes. Then, at query time, you use that information to make good guesses for the actual distance between two arbitrary nodes (by estimating them over a close landmark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a heuristic that estimates (lower bounds) the minimum path cost between two nodes there are two possibilities (that I know of):

**Knowledge about the underlying space the graph is part of**

As an example assume the nodes are points on a plane (with x and y coordinate) and the cost of each edge is the euclidean distance between the corresponding nodes. In this case you can estimate (lower bound) the path cost from node `U` to node `V` by calculating the euclidean distance between `U.position` and `V.position`.

Another example would be a road network where you know its lying on the earth surface. The cost on the edges might represent travel times in minutes. In order to estimate the path cost from node `U` to node `V` you can calculate the great-circle distance between the two and divide it by the maximum travel speed possible.

**Graph Embedding**

Another possibility is to embed your graph in a space where you can estimate the path distance between two nodes efficiently. This approach does not make any assumptions on the underlying space but requires precomputation.

For example you could define a landmark `L` in your graph. Then you precalculate the distance between each node of the graph to your landmark and safe this distance at the node. In order to estimate the path distance during A* search you can now use the precalculated distances as follows: The path distance between node `U` and `V` is lower bounded by `|dist(U, L) - dist(V,L)|`.You can improve this heuristic by using more than one landmark.

For your graph you could use node A and node H as landmarks, which will give you the graph embedding as shown in the image below. You would have to precompute the shortest paths between the nodes A and H and all other nodes beforehand in order to compute this embedding. When you want to estimate for example the distance between two nodes B and J you can compute the distance in each of the two dimensions and use the maximum of the two distances as estimation. This corresponds to the [L-infinity norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity).

[image: graph embedding]

Comment: Great explanation! 
I am currently creating 2D game for maze escape problem and thinking to use A* as based algorithm. Could you suggest me how should I calculate the heuristic value for my maze problem?

Comment: @MinKhantLu Take a look at typical shortest paths. Are they like **as-the-crows-fly** (straight line) in almost all cases? If so, use it as heuristic. It is the simplest heuristic and can be used in many game applications. Don't use it for road or transit networks, it will perform very bad there. **Landmark heuristic** is always a good generic choice, but it needs pre-computation and space (no problem for google maps, but probably for your game)

Comment: Oh sorry, just noted you are talking about mazes and not games in general. A maze typically has no common sense of *correct direction*. The shortest path is almost always super complicated and goes into all directions. It is likely that you won't be able to achieve non-trivial improvements over ordinary Dijkstra (depending on how complex they are). If you can identify some kind of frequently used edges in your mazes (like a highway), then you could also give **contraction hierarchies** a try.

Comment: @MinKhantLu i see two possibilities. Either you assume no walls for your heuristic. Or you could use some points in your maze as  and use the landmark approach.

Comment: @SaiBot if I assume no walls for my heuristic. Could we still get the correct shortest path? I guess in some cases, we would fail to get the shortest path.

Comment: @MinKhantLu No matter what heuristic you choose, you will always get the shortest path (as long as your heuristic was a heuristic, i.e. **admissable** and **monotone**). Only the time you need to find it changes. If you think away the walls, you actually use *as-the-crows-fly* (straight line) distance. It works well if shortest paths look like a straight line from `A` to `B` in most cases. Which they probably don't for mazes.

Comment: @Zabuza What if I find heuristic value of u by using  Euclidean distance from u to target node. Can I still get the shortest path ?

Comment: @MinKhantLu All your examples describe the same heuristic: the length of a straight line from `A` to `B`. This is known as *as-the-crows-fly* (or *straight-line*) distance. So yes, this is a heuristic. It performs well if there are no obstacles. It performs bad if there are many obstacles. In a maze it probably does not perform well. More general: The heuristic performs well if the guessed distance is close to the real length of the path. That is, if their *path-guess* looks similar to the actual shortest path. The *straight-line* doesn't look like a typical shortest path in mazes, does it?

Comment: @Zabuza 
Really thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot.

Comment: @MinKhantLu You're welcome. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/iMGe6q0.jpg) is a small comparison of some Dijkstra variants on a typical road graph. The query is from north to south and every mark represents a node that was visited by the algorithm. The less marks, the faster the algorithm was. Another typical (still pretty new) routing algorithm is **contraction hierarchies**. I didn't implement it back then, but it performs really well for road networks. **Landmarks** is usually the heuristic to choose.

Answer (score 2):

The heuristic is an estimate of the **additional distance** you would have to traverse to get to your destination.

It is problem specific and appears in different forms for different problems. For your graph , a good heuristic could be: *the actual distance from the node to destination, measured by an inch tape or centimeter scale.* Funny right but thats exactly how my college professor did it. He took an inch tape on black board and came up with very good heuristic.

So h(A) could be 10 units means the length measured by a measuring scale physically from A to J.

Of course for your algorithm to work the heuristic must be [**admissible**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), if not it could give you wrong answer.

Comment: Oops, I have never thought like that. Thanks for your answer.
And if it is problem specific. How should I search heuristic value for maze problem ?

Comment: @MinKhantLu neither did I or anyone in the class in that lecture.

Comment: I gave the answer regarding what could be a good heuristic? Clearly said in the answer.

Comment: @phil13131 Please tell us if you have a better heuristic. By the way heuristic means estimate.

Comment: @SumeetSingh Finding an admissable heuristic on an abstract graph is highly non-trivial and depends on many aspects of the graph, e.g., are edges directed or not, does it have loops, etc.. But I just wanted to point out that you cannot simply "measure it with a ruler" if the graph itself is not "layed out" the way the edges are described. Just looking at vertex I, gives you 4 edges with lengths that do not correspond to the actual lengths on the picture, so measuring has no meaning here.